# Issue with dir is other-writeable but not sticky (blue text, green background on all directories)

Tags: command-line, permissions, chmod

Some background:

> **Distro:** Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
>
> **Experience level:** Not new to Linux, but not an expert.

The issue: When working with SMART Tools to check an external USB drive, somehow I managed to change the attributes on all of the directories on the external drive so they no longer appear blue text w/ black background using ls. They are now showing in ls as blue text w/ a green background.

I was under the impression that this meant the sticky bit was removed from all of the directories, however `chmod +t` and `chmod 1777` have not resolved them back to their default blue text w/ black background.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: So are the permissions actually incorrect, or is it just the LS_COLORS?

Comment: It doesn't appear that the permissions are wrong, however the LS_COLORS have change from the blue text/black background to the blue text/green background.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly normal on drives formatted with NTFS, since NTFS does not support Unix-style permissions (and as such, trying to change the permissions of a file or directory on that drive will do nothing), and Ubuntu, by default, sets the permissions of NTFS mountpoints to 777. However, you can set the permissions manually at mount time with the `umask` option:

```
sudo umount /dev/your_usb_stick
sudo mount -o umask=002 /dev/your_usb_stick /path/to/mountpoint
```

Note that the value for `umask` is actually the *inverse* of the permissions you want; this will set the permissions to 775.

Also, with default `LS_COLORS` at least, a green background for directories isn't changed by setting the sticky bit; the only way you can get rid of it is to make the directory not be other-writable.

Bottom line: If your drive is formatted with NTFS, try mounting it with the option `umask=002`. If it's formatted with ext2/3/4, try running `chmod o-w` on the directories that are green.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the NTFS information. The drive is NTFS so I wll add the umount options and post the results. I am still curious however on where I would need to look (log perhaps) to understand why the LS_COLORS are different now. As of last week the directories were not highlighted in green.